# ngFor for each category

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

Hi I'm new to Ionic/Angular and I want to know how `ngFor` works.

I have a website and want to create an app to this website with Ionic.
The website has a shop which has 4 categories:

- chocolate
- plate
- dragee
- basket

I want use `ngFor` for each category. Every category has a slide. How can I realize this?
This code shows all products:

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let product of products">
```

How can I use `ngFor` to show specific category.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific usage case, it is difficult to use as ngFor doesn't go well with slides. Check out https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/ for more usage.

However, if you were dealing with a list or another item of that kind, you would use ngFor in the following way:

First you define an array in your Typescript file containing information about the categories.

Then you use ngFor to loop over those items so that you can access them (and their contents) in each item.

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let category of categoryDefinedInTypescriptFile">
         <h1>category.title</h1>
   </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```